# Знаки вопроса вместо кириллицы в JSON

Tags: java, json

Здравствуйте. Меня интересует как можно решить проблему с отображением знаков вопроса вместо кириллических символов в JSON полученном Ajax-запросом.
Практически все темы найденные при помощи поиска советуют установить кодовую страницу, но в моем случае это никак не поможет так как объявление кодовой страницы у меня стоит с самого начала вместе с объявлением mime-типа. Дебагер так же показал что сервер передает нормальный JSON.

```
 PrintWriter outs = response.getWriter();
 SprIzmDao dao = new SprIzmDao();
 int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
 EdIzmBean bean=dao.getIzmObj(i);
 response.setContentType("application/json");
 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
 outs.print(bean.toString());
 outs.flush();
```

Как видите код очень прост. Возможно ошибка в нем кроется на виду, но я почему то её в упор не вижу.

Comment: Как я понял ошибка в кодировке? Тебе вместо текста выводятся крякозябры?

Comment: Знаки вопроса. при любой кодировке на странице браузера.

Comment: Хммм, странно, и что интересно код совсем простой.. Я думаю ошибка кроется в классах `SprIzmDao` или `EdIzmBean`..

Comment: дебагер показал что в respons уходит валидный JSON. значит что дао берет с базы валидные данные и формирует валидный бин, да и база в UTF-8.

Comment: Drakonoved вы про jquery?

Comment: В отладчике хрома вы видите русские буквы в ответе сервера? возможно дело в настройках сервлет-контейнера или что там вы используете на сервер-сайде. Вот тут как настроить utf-8 для tomcat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps

Comment: Rafael Osipov в отладчике в ответе тоже знаки вопроса. Попробовал повторить алгоритм как в информации переданой вами по ссылке, все бестолку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось проблема была в том что кодировка символов устанавливается после создания потока вывода.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");    
PrintWriter outs = response.getWriter();
SprIzmDao dao = new SprIzmDao();
int i = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
EdIzmBean bean=dao.getIzmObj(i);
outs.print(bean.toString());
outs.flush();
```